# Does any one know about opensource network monitor tool for black berry?

Tags: blackberry, networking

Does any one know about opensource network monitor tool for BlackBerry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about RIM [Network Diagnostic Tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0) (source is available):

> BlackBerry smartphones support many different transports that facilitate reliable data communication between third-party applications and the Internet. The transports available are direct Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), BlackBerry® Mobile Data System (BlackBerry MDS), BlackBerry® Internet Service Browsing (BIS-B), BlackBerry® Unite!™ software, Wireless Access Protocol (WAP)1.0, WAP2.0 and Wi-Fi® technology. It is important to understand the differences between these transports and how and when to leverage each transport. It is also crucial to determine if a transport is available for use before trying to use it. The Network Diagnostic Tool is essentially a role model that answers all these questions and is a functional diagnostic tool for testing a URL over various transports supported by the BlackBerry solutions, as well as for displaying the values of many network attributes during the test period.

Comment: that was a good example, but does this app shows network bandwidth information?